# Вывод данных в RecyclerView используя Room

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста как используя Room из готовой БД вывести данные в RecyclerView? По примеру с сайта https://inducesmile.com/android/android-room-with-livedata-example-tutorial попытался сделать адаптер, и все остальные классы для работы с Room, но не понял как из готовой БД вывести данные.

Еще не смог понять как после выгрузки нажав на элемент передать id в другое активити.

Класс Bludo (сам объект)

```
@Entity
public class Bludo {

    @PrimaryKey
    public long id;
    public String name;
    public String description;
    public String image;
    public String favorites;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

Интерфейс BludoDao

```
@Dao
public interface BludoDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM bludo")
    List<Bludo> getAll();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM bludo WHERE id = :id")
    Bludo getById(long id);
}
```

Класс AppDatabase

```
@Database(entities = {Bludo.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract BludoDao bludoDao();
    private static AppDatabase appDatabase;
    private Context context;
    public static AppDatabase getInstance(Context context){

        if(appDatabase == null){
            appDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "test")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build();
        }
        return appDatabase;
    }

    public static void destroyInstance() {
        appDatabase = null;
    }
}
```

Класс RoomViewHolder

```
public class RoomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView txtName;
    public TextView txtDescription;

    public RoomViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        txtName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        txtDescription = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
    }
}
```

Класс RoomAdapter

```
public class RoomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RoomViewHolder>  {

    private List<Bludo> bludoList;
    private Context context;
    public RoomAdapter(Context context, List<Bludo> bludoList) {
        this.bludoList = bludoList;
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public RoomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        return new RoomViewHolder(view);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RoomViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Bludo bludo = bludoList.get(position);

        holder.txtName.setText(bludo.getName());
        holder.txtDescription.setText(bludo.getDescription());
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return bludoList.size();
    }

}
```

Класс MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RoomAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RecyclerView rvList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvList);
        rvList.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, 1));
        rvList.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        BludoDao bludoDao = (BludoDao) AppDatabase.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).bludoDao();
        List<Bludo> list = bludoDao.getAll();
        adapter = new RoomAdapter(this, list);
        rvList.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Вроде разобрался с вопросом.

**Класс AppDatabase переделал так:**

```
@Database(entities = {Bludo.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract BludoDao bludoDao();

    private static final String DB_NAME = "test.db";

    public static AppDatabase createPersistentDatabase(Context context) {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase.class, DB_NAME)
                .openHelperFactory(new AssetSQLiteOpenHelperFactory())
                .build();
    }
}
```

**В MainActivity вызывается так:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RoomAdapter adapter;
    RecyclerView rvList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rvList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvList);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        rvList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        BludoDao bludoDao = (BludoDao) AppDatabase.createPersistentDatabase(getApplicationContext()).bludoDao();
        bludoDao.getAll().observe(this, (List<Bludo> bludoList) -> {
            adapter = new RoomAdapter(MainActivity.this, bludoList);
            rvList.setAdapter(adapter);
        });

    }
}
```

**Интерфейс BludoDao:**

```
@Dao
public interface BludoDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM bludo")
    public LiveData<List<Bludo>> getAll();
}
```